# It is normal for glass-ceramic cooktop to be hot?

Tags: electrical

I just bought a stove with glass-ceramic cooktop and I'm frustrated because when I use one hot plate the whole cooktop is hot (even the metal corpus around it). Is this normal or the cooktop must be cold except working hot plate?

Comment: This is definitely not standard behavior. Something is weird here.

Comment: ...or maybe the cooktop is so stunningly good-looking? ;-) (HOT)

Comment: I use non-induction heating but I was thinking that the glass must remain cold (except working hot plate). Please give me more opinions if this is normal or not because I have no friends with ceramic stoves to ask (the all use gas cooking stoves).

Comment: @StevenSmith  I just checked this question on google pages in my country. People are saying that ceramic cooktop may behave like that (I mean, it may be ok that more than the under-pot plate is hot), but I my understanding of HSE matters (safety, for that matter) tells me that if corpus is hot, too, it may cause a risk of damage/incinerate shelves (depends on the temperature). You may want ot contact producer to explain this.

Comment: @MarekOleszczuk What made me tick was also the corpus. No appliance manufacturer is going to risk a user getting a burn and then suing them, not good for business.

Comment: how hot? do you have a temperature number to work with? we use a ceramic cooktop, and almost the entire thing gets warm, specially when the larger burners are used. not hot as in enough to burn, but definitely warmer than ambient.

Answer (score 1):

No, it definitely sounds like there may be an issue with the contacts. If the cooktop is relatively new, contact the installer/manufacturer to decide if you have received a faulty product.